# Extracting information from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, nlp, rule-engine

I have the below dataframe. I want to build a rule engine to extract the tokens where the pattern is like  Eg. "UNITED STATES" .What is the best way to do it ? Is there anything like regex or [CGUL](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/EIM/CGUL+Tips+and+Tricks+for+Entity+Extraction) for this kind of tasks? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
WORD_INDEX  WORD_TOKEN  WORD_POS
0           TRUMP       PROPN
1           IS          ADP
2           THE         ADP
3           PRESIDENT   NOUN
4           OF          ADP
5           THE         ADP
6           UNITED      NOUN
7           STATES      NOUN
```

I want to start with WORD_POS and find the WORD_TOKEN. Any idea how to do that? For example, I want to find the WORD_TOKENs where the WORD_POS is NOUN and then next WORD_POS is also NOUN.

Comment: Can you divide tokens to `UNITED` and `STATES` then check the first token and then the following token?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the `contains` string method, which takes a regex argument by default. For example

```
mask = df['WORD_TOKEN'].str.contains('(UNITED|STATES)')
print(df[mask])
```

This will match anything containing "united" or "states".

Comment: I want to do it the other way round, I want to start with WORD_POS  and find the WORD_TOKEN. Any idea how to do that? For example, I want to find the WORD_TOKENs where the WORD_POS is NOUN and then next WORD_POS is also NOUN.