# How to extract URL from Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I need to extract URLs from a column of DataFrame which was created using following values

```
creation_date,tweet_id,tweet_text
2020-06-06 03:01:37,1269102116364324865,#Webinar: Sign up for @SumoLogic's June 16 webinar to learn how to navigate your #Kubernetes environment and unders… https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42237666/extracting-information-from-pandas-dataframe
2020-06-06 01:29:38,1269078966985461767,"In this #webinar replay, @DisneyStreaming's @rothgar chats with @SumoLogic's @BenoitNewton about how #Kubernetes is… https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46928636/pandas-split-list-into-columns-with-regex
```

column name `tweet_text` contains URL. I am trying following code.

```
df["tweet_text"]=df["tweet_text"].astype(str)
pattern = r'https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)'

df['links'] = ''
df['links']= df["tweet_text"].str.extract(pattern, expand=True)

print(df)
```

I am using regex from answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url) and it matches URL in both rows.[image: screenshot]
But I am getting `NaN` as values of new column `df['links]'`. I have also tried solution provided in first answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028932/how-to-extract-specific-content-in-a-pandas-dataframe-with-a-regex), which was

```
df['links']= df["tweet_text"].str.extract(pattern, expand=False).str.strip()
```

But I am getting following error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Lastly I created an empty column using `df['links'] = ''`, because I was getting `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1` error. If that's relevant. 
Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Your URL pattern is not quite clean, but the main problem is that it contains *capturing* groups where you need *non-capturing* ones. You need to wrap it with a capturing group, `pattern = r'(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&/=]*)'`

Comment: It worked thank you, can you move this comment to answers so I can mark it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main problem is that your URL pattern contains *capturing groups* where you need *non-capturing ones*. You need to replace all `(` with `(?:` in the pattern.

However, it is not enough since `str.extract` requires a capturing group in the pattern so that it could return any value at all. Thus, you need to wrap the whole pattern with a capturing group.

You may use

```
pattern = r'(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&/=]*)'
```

Note the `+` is not necessary to escape inside a character class. Also, there is no need to use `//` inside  a character class, one `/` is enough.