# How to extract a URL in free text?

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, parsing, url

I'm working with some pretty dirty text data that is currently in a csv and I'm looking to to extract URLs from it to do some processing. I have already referenced a few sources here on SO on how to more intelligently extract the urls. I started regex more similar to the top answer here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839994/extracting-a-url-in-python) and am currently working with some regex similar to the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62229836/how-to-extract-url-from-pandas-dataframe) post.

However, neither of these take into account when a url has some unwanted text directly after it without any spaces. Take for example "https://example.com/exampleurl," or "https://example.com/exampleurl|unwantedtext". The two unwanted examples here being "," and "|unwantedtext".

I am looking to edit my regex to be able to detect valid urls more accurately. If the url isn't of a valid format I'd like to mark that. I'm currently working within a pandas dataframe so when I extract the urls it looks something like this:

```
def parseURL(data):
    URLpattern = r'(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}[-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&/=]*)'
    data['parsed_url'] = data['free_text'].str.extract(URLpattern)
```

This will successfully get me "https://example.com" out of the string "I like https://example.com a lot" but it won't successfully retrieve it successfully from "I like https://example.com, a lot"

Answer (score -2):

You can use this:

```
import re
 
with open("yourfile.txt") as file:
        for line in file:
            urls = re.findall('https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', line)
            print(urls)
```